# How to catch ContextErrorException

Tags: php, symfony

how to catch `ContextErrorException` in Symfony ?

I get

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime
>   could not be converted to string

when I try to

```
try {
   $html .= strval($value);
}
catch(ContextErrorException $e){ }
```

Why it isn't catchable?

Comment: namespace issues ? try `catch (\ContextErrorException $e) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the correct namespace in symfony

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException $e) {
    // do something with the exception
}
```

I tried that with symfony 2.8 and it worked.